# How to handle zip files that contain files with empty filenames

Tags: java, unzip, zip

I am using `java.util.zip` to extract zip files, though when I run it on a particular zip file, I get

`java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file`

Going forward, I open the zip file using windows explorer, but it doesn't see anything. If I use the extraction utility built into windows, it says the zip file is invalid.

I extracted it using 7zip and it worked fine, so I opened it up and noticed this: there is a folder with no filename.

[image: img]

[image: img]

I am not sure how to open this zip file. I wasn't even aware that you could have filenames with no characters, or that there are applications written in such a way that considers this...

What are some solutions I can try?

One solution I have thought of is to just exec 7zip and have it handle the file since it works anyways, but I will have to include the 7zip files with the application since the end-users may not have 7zip on their machines.

Comment: Looks like the name is just whitespace. Why are you trying to find nasty solution for this exeptional case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows won't allow empty folder names, or folder names with just spaces, whereas 7zip will allow you to create folders in a zip with just spaces for the folder name.

You'll need to check for empty strings in the filename returned by ZipEntry.

```
private static String fixFileName(String filename)
{
    String[] sArray = filename.split("\\s+");
    String retval = "";
    for (String s : sArray)
    {
        if (s.trim().equals(""))
        {
            s = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
        retval += s;
    }

    return retval;
}
```